# Path in the URL using HTACCESS

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I do a redirect without changin the url from any file to a specific PHP file and add as a GET the path?

for example, if I'll try to enter to

> www.example.net/this/is/the/path.png

The browser will show me whats in

> www.example.net/view.php?path=this%2Fis%2Fthe%2Fpath.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^((?!view).*)$ view?path=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: There is no view file, there is view.php, and when I do `RewriteRule ^((?!view.php/).*)$ view.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]`, Chrome return error code `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.